# Is there any method that creates another arraylist with the common values of two arraylists?

Tags: java, arraylist, compare

That is, if I have the next:

```
ArrayList<Integer> array1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> array2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

array1 ==> (1,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18)
array2 ==> (1,17,18)
```

Is there any method that creates another arraylist with the common values?

Comment: A more efficient solution is possible if the two lists are always sorted (as in your example). Is this always true?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this `ArrayList` method:

[`ArrayList#retainAll(java.util.Collection)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

So, put this in your code.

```
 array1.retainAll(array2 );
```

Example==>

```
      List<Integer> first_list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        first_list.add(10);
        first_list.add(20);
        first_list.add(30);

        List<Integer> second_list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        second_list.add(40);
        second_list.add(20);
        second_list.add(30);

       List<Integer> third_list = new ArrayList<Integer>(second_list);
third_list.retainAll(first_list);

        for (int i = 0; i < third_list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("===>" + third_list.get(i));
        }
```

Finally we can see here that , the third_list is having only common elements between lists first_list and second_list.

Comment: No problem dude!! sometimes it happens with all,and sharing things and knowledge is all about stackoverflow :)

Comment: Note that this modifies `array1`. If you want to keep `array1` and `array2` unmodified but produce a third array that contains just the shared items, `retainAll` isn't going to help.

Comment: Great!!!! Thank you. What is the result, array1 has the coincidence of the compare or what? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over one list and check if value is present in another list

```
ArrayList<Integer> common = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i: array1){
  if(array2.contains(i)){
     common.add(i);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (Integer value : array1)
{
   if (array2.contains(value))
    {
       result.add(value);
     }
}
```

Comment: Not necessary, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22808207/2959259)

Answer (score 0):

You could use apache commons library and use `ListUtils.intersection(list1,list2)` method.